# Query regrading updating sellerFeeBasisPoints

Tags: web3.js, metaplex-js, node.js

Is it possible to update NFT `sellerFeeBasisPoints` with `@metaplex-foundation/js` if the collection authority is not same as nft update authority? I'm using -

```
const transaction = metaplex.nfts().builders().update({ nftOrSft: fetchNft, sellerFeeBasisPoints: royalty }).toTransaction();
await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [ wallet ]);
```

Getting this error -

```
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x39
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (C:\Users\DELL\Discord\Bot\test\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:6736:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (C:\Users\DELL\Discord\Bot\test\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:6693:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (C:\Users\DELL\Discord\Bot\test\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:6683:12)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (C:\Users\DELL\Discord\Bot\test\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:2210:21)
    at async C:\Users\DELL\Discord\Bot\test\solana.js:17:20 {
  logs: [
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: Unverify Collection',
    'Program log: Incorrect account owner',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 2785 of 400000 compute units',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x39'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: I answered to this question @Dodecahedr0x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a person in Metaplex discord server, found what I was doing wrong. As we can also update/remove/add collection to a NFT with that method, thus the method requires a collection to be set either it's the same or updated like this -

```
const transaction = metaplex.nfts().builders().update({ nftOrSft: fetchNft, sellerFeeBasisPoints: royalty, collection: fetchNft?.collection?.address }).toTransaction();
```

In the above method, setting the collection ensures that the collection of that NFT is not being updated in the process.